# Read word file in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am trying to read a word/PDF document to create a JSON object in Angular or even JavaScript.
Any Ideas as to any library or function I could use?

Comment: `.docx` files use an XML dialect so there are plenty of options. Is there any particular reason you are trying to do this client side? Regardless, extracting text from a word document is straightforward enough while for PDF files it can be a nightmare.

Comment: I initially thought of doing it on the server side with Java but the server side script support is too limited and runs PHP only. Hence thought of using JavaScript I do understand the challenge of working with pdf as it is in a binary format. Any Libraries or ideas for extracting data froma word file??

Comment: I haven't done it in JavaScript but there are plenty of XML libraries available. I assume you just want to extract the text which simply means traversing all the nodes and extracting their contents.